# Updating running list if event happens

Tags: count, stata, repeat

sample Data:

```
clear

* Input data

input student CITATION EXPELLED hadCITATION hadEXPELLED
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 1 0
2 1 0 1 0
2 0 0 1 0
3 1 0 1 0
3 0 1 1 1
3 1 1 1 1
3 1 0 1 1
3 1 0 1 1
4 . . . .
4 . 0 . 0
4 0 0 0 0
4 0 1 0 1
4 1 0 1 0
```

I want to create these hadCITATION and hadEXPELLED variable columns that update based on the responses of CITATION and EXPELLED.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Pearly Spencer. Student 2 does not have any CITATION or EXPULSION in there first response so the HAD variables are both 0. This is also true for student 2 second response so the HAD variables are both 0 still. Then at student 2 thirds response they have a citation so hereafter the hadCITATION variable equals to 1 for that student

Comment: I don't find this clear either. You should certainly fold your comment back into the question. Also, please be more careful with spelling, punctuation, etc.

Comment: You're more or less permanently at odds with recommendations, in that SO isn't really about us writing code for you. You are expected, at least by me, to show us your code attempt and also explain why it is still problematic.

Comment: @bvowe Your data do not make sense. Equally puzzling you accepted an answer which gives different results without providing any explanation.

Comment: I am mostly in agreement with @Pearly Spencer and specifically downvoting for lack of clarity. The key point is that SO is not just a vehicle to provide code for an individual. You're expected to make your question clear and answer secondary questions. The simple and crucial ideal is that the thread should be helpful to other users in the future, and more than a way for someone to get one-to-one help in public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help. I can't see that this makes sense without a time or sequence variable. My guess is that once you've had a CITATION or EXPULSION, then that's your history. The rules may be more complicated, but I can't see that you're explaining them. **I can't see the rationale for your example for student 4.**

```
clear 
input student CITATION EXPELLED hadCITATION hadEXPELLED
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 1 0
2 1 0 1 0
2 0 0 1 0
3 1 0 1 0
3 0 1 1 1
3 1 1 1 1
3 1 0 1 1
3 1 0 1 1
4 . . . .
4 . 0 . 0
4 0 0 0 0
4 0 1 0 1
4 1 0 1 0
end 

gen long time = _n 

bysort student (time) : gen want1 = sum(CITATION) > 0 

by student: gen want2 = sum(EXPELLED) > 0 

list student CIT EXP hadCIT hadEXP want?, sepby(student) 

    +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | student   CITATION   EXPELLED   hadCIT~N   hadEXP~D   want1   want2 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |       1          0          0          0          0       0       0 |
  2. |       1          0          0          0          0       0       0 |
  3. |       1          0          0          0          0       0       0 |
  4. |       1          0          0          0          0       0       0 |
  5. |       1          0          0          0          0       0       0 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |       2          0          0          0          0       0       0 |
  7. |       2          0          0          0          0       0       0 |
  8. |       2          1          0          1          0       1       0 |
  9. |       2          1          0          1          0       1       0 |
 10. |       2          0          0          1          0       1       0 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
 11. |       3          1          0          1          0       1       0 |
 12. |       3          0          1          1          1       1       1 |
 13. |       3          1          1          1          1       1       1 |
 14. |       3          1          0          1          1       1       1 |
 15. |       3          1          0          1          1       1       1 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
 16. |       4          .          .          .          .       0       0 |
 17. |       4          .          0          .          0       0       0 |
 18. |       4          0          0          0          0       0       0 |
 19. |       4          0          1          0          1       0       1 |
 20. |       4          1          0          1          0       1       1 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```